# Postgres - Find out what machine ran sql query

Tags: postgresql

We have an dev environment where everyone uses the same functional ID.   Someone ran a query that caused alot of duplicates in a table.  Nobody is confessing to doing it.  We found the offending query using this query.

SELECT
pss.*,
pd.*
FROM pg_stat_statements pss, pg_database pd
WHERE pd.oid=pss.dbid AND query ~* '<#######>'
DESC

My problem is that this query does not show the machine name.   Does anybody know if there is any other table I can join to get the machine name that ran the bad query?

Comment: if your `log_line_prefix` includes `%r` or `%h`, and you set `log_statement` or `log_min_duration_statement` so that the offending query gets printed, you may be able identify the source of the query